# mutiple or conditions on a While loop in python in python

Tags: python

Have forgotten how to declare multiple conditions on a while loop

Its going to take one of the input and check the user has entered either of the 4 correct letters. Currently however, it always drops into the loop

```
temp = input()
while temp.lower() != ("a" or "b" or "c" or "d"):
    print("Error, you must enter either A, B, C or D")
    print(inventory())
    print("What would you like to buy?")
    temp = input()
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitely you would have to write

```
while (temp.lower() != "a") and (temp.lower() != "b")....... :
```

but you might want to try

```
while temp.lower()[0] not in 'abcd':
```

However, note the indexing I added here to the lowered input variable, as otherwise substrings of `'abcd'` of length > 1 would match, too.

Comment: daaam yea, I have not coded for 6 months and over complicating things. that fixed it, as soon as I can ill accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider

```
while temp.lower() not in ('a','b','c','d'):
    print("Error")
```

Don't know why one would do this but still here's an option:

```
import string
while temp.lower() not in string.ascii_lowercase[:4]:
    print("Error")
```